# How to get the number before percentage symbol in a string?

Tags: javascript

These are some possible strings. The number percentage is always at beginning.

var string = "0.5% - corresponding something" or var string = "23% - correspondig something";

I need to get the the entire number before the percentage symbol.

I already tried some solutions in cutting the string, but the problem is that the number doesn't have always the same length.

Can you help me?

Comment: `parseFloat` will do the job here in this instance already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions. For example:

```js
let antani = "23% - correspondig something";
// using parseFloat
console.log(parseFloat(antani));
// using split
console.log(antani.split("%")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

first split string using '%'

```html
<script>
var str = "0.5% - corresponding something";
  var res = str.split("%");
  number=res[0];
  console.log(res[0]);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular expression you can match the numbers (including dots) before the percentage sign.
Example:

```
var text = "0.5% - corresponding something";
var percentageRegex = /([0-9\.]+).+/;
var matches = percentageRegex.exec(text);

console.log(matches[1]);
```